# Changing $PATH variable

Tags: shell, unix, path

I used this to add to PATH:

```
APXS2=/usr/local/apache/bin/apxs PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/apache/bin passenger-install-apache2-module
```

and my PATH now looks like this:

```
/usr/local/jdk/bin:/usr/kerberos/sbin:/usr/kerberos/bin:/usr/lib/courier-imap/sbin:/usr/lib/courier-imap/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin:/root/bin:
```

Now I want to remove this I added. How to do this?

Answer (score 1):

The best way might be to simply store a copy of the path before altering it.

```
PATH_BAK=$PATH
PATH=...
...
PATH=$PATH_BAK
```

Answer (score 1):

Just log out, login again and your PATH will be reset.

Answer (score 0):

If you forgot to create a backup you can use the substring removal/replace.

Substring Removal

```
${string#substring}
```

Substring Replace

```
${string/substring/replacement}
```

Please refer to this link http://www.museum.state.il.us/ismdepts/library/linuxguides/abs-guide/string-manipulation.html

Comment: So what is the answer here ? Your answer does not manipulate the value of PATH - if it needed modifying anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Given /usr/local/apache/bin isn't in the '... my PATH now looks like this ...' - what do you think you added ? Assuming you're on bash or ksh - you didn't actually change the path because you didn't export it. So I doubt you need to remove anything.

E.g.

```
$ echo $PATH
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin
$ PATH=$PATH:/foo /bin/ls
aFile
$ echo $PATH
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin
$ # PATH did not alter
```

Versus:

```
$ echo $PATH
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin
$ export PATH=$PATH:/foo
$ /bin/ls
aFile
$ echo $PATH
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/foo
$ #PATH modified.
```

So unless you exported the new PATH to the shell you're invoking the command from the PATH did not alter.